# How does sbt determine that it needs to update

Tags: scala, sbt, lxc

I've tried to run application inside firejail without network. When I run sbt in host system, all goes ok, sbt finds all libraries. Then I try to run sbt inside restricted environment with read-write access to ~/.sbt, ~/.ivy2, ~/.m2 and project folders and read-only access to .sbt binary. Sbt loses all dependent libraries and try go get them from network, which is disabled.

Where do sbt store library cache and why do it refuse to take old compiled and ready to use state?

---

*update*: sbt fails on the time it tries to build global plugins. It does not get to the stage where it performs project build. I've tried to add offline := true both to the project and global sbt configuration, but sbt tries to update plugins nevertheless.

---

*update2*: I've managed to run sbt successfully without rebuilding all global plugins. That requires access to /etc. But I would prefer not to give access to /etc. What information do SBT need from /etc? Hostname or something else? Why on earth it make cache depend on such things?

---

*update3*:
I've discovered the exact cause for SBT failing to recognize already downloaded libraries. `/etc/passwd` is strictly needed for SBT to work correctly. Could anyone point in what way SBT uses login info exactly?

Comment: Have you tried to configure SBT to run offline? https://github.com/sbt/sbt/wiki/User-Stories:--Offline-mode-and-Dependency-Locking

Comment: thanks for advice, but sbt still tries to update plugins